# Is there an intent to replicate pressing PlayTo

Tags: android, android-intent, tasker, miracast

We are looking for an Android intent that we can use to trigger the PlayTo menu to appear. This way we can have the menu appear by sending the intent (using tasker) instead of having to navigate through the notification bar at the top of the screen.

We are doing this on an Asus Zenpad 10. Essentially we are looking for the simplest way of displaying the miracast devices available - the PlayTo feature does this.

Is there anyway of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: are you trying connect directly to PlayTo or starting an intent that triggers certain apps (video player in this case) ?

Comment: @EgeKuzubasioglu I am trying to have an intent which is as if I pressed the PlayTo button. I just want a way to open the PlayTo menu (see the miracast devices) without having to go through the notification bar at the top of the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is by Google's design not possible. User has to invoke that menu self.

You didn't specify what is the target device you'll be playing to. If it is a Chromecast, then you could try one of those Tasker plugins:

- `AutoCast` app by joaoapps
- `SecureSettings`

maybe they'll also work in your case, but that's a long shot